# MVC4 EditorForModel template for EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In an MVC4 web application using the Razor engine and entity framework, is it possible to create a template for use with the html helper @Html.EditorForModel , so that entities with links to other tables are better displayed.

The example I am working with is a DbContext containing two DBSets, Regions and Schools. There are many regions, and a school may belong to one region. Ideally I would like the editor for schools to show a dropdown of regions to select from. I would like to make a template that is generic enough so that I can just call the @Html.EditorForModel helper and the form is generated in one go, and that I could make changes to the region or schools tables later on and for the changes to be reflected in the edit form without me needing to make alterations.

Some code:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext ()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }

    [Table("Regions")]
    public class Region
    {
        public Region()
        {
            Schools = new List<School>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string RegionName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<School> Schools { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Schools")]
    public class School
    {
        public School() { }

        [Key]
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Region")]
        public int RegionId { get; set; }

        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have created a partial view to create display the editor form, with the idea that I can pass in either a Region or a School as the view model.

```
@model object
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{           
    @Html.ValidationSummary("Broken stuff:")
    @Html.EditorForModel()               
}
```

I don't know if this is possible, but I would really like the new template to loop over the properties of the entity and detect if there is a linked table (e.g. School contains a Region) and display the list of regions in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off corse you can. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17760548/1814343) to see how.

An alternation is that you use scaffolding and let it to create your views. Most of times(!) it creates correct DropDowns for you and you just customize your view if you want.

And in those few situations that yo see strange DDLs, you just need to correct `ValueName` and `DataName` parameters in the related action methods whic return list items to the view...

Answer (score 2):

Well, in general, it's a bad idea to pass your data models directly to your views for rendering.  There are security issues there, among other things.  But, even if you are going to do this you would not want to pass your entire data context like that because it's not structured in a way that is suitable for rendering in a web page.