# @Html.EditorForModel() Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on **MVC4** , `using  @Html.EditorForModel()` , it is showing `dropdownlist` as a text box, I want to show `Dropdown` list by setting any `attribute` and overriding template. Please share me **MVC4** example for this.

```
@model Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a view model that will represent a dropdown:

```
public class ItemsViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

which will be used in your main view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ItemsViewModel DropDown1 { get; set; }
    public ItemsViewModel DropDown2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now all that's left is write a custom editor template for the `ItemsViewModel` which should be placed in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ItemsViewModel.cshtml`. Notice that the name and location of the template is important:

```
@model ItemViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

and that's pretty much all it takes.

Comment: Hi , I am using @HTML.EditorForModel() which means it load the model runtime , no code

Comment: Sure, in my example the model is `MyViewModel`. All you have in your main view is: `@model MyViewModel @Html.EditorForModel()`.

Comment: I understand that you are using EditorForModel but that's not a problem at all. It should still work.

Comment: So as per your example runtime it bounds to dropdown as per model returning ItemViewModel , that's good one but can it be possible to override with an  attribute  through data annotations such as DropdownList or something

Comment: Yes, you can use the `UIHint("TemplateName")` attribute in order to override the convention. In this case the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TemplateName.cshtml` will be rendered for the specified property. But if you rely on the standard naming convention in which the template name is the name of the type you don't even need to be decorating your model with UIHint.

Comment: Hi Darin, How can I make this template to all my entity models without changing return type or create new viewmodel  as  public ItemsViewModel DropDown1 { get; set; }

Answer (score -1):

It's the overriding template a requisite? You could use the `@Html.DropDownList()` helper.

There is a full example about how to use in the asp.net website and you can download the project: [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: I am looking similar way as below to override in MVC4 ,it's old one in MVC2  and not working now. http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/11/27/extending-asp-net-mvc-2-templates.aspx