# EditForModel for dropdown mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

We are using dynamic view with EditorForModel()

```
@model dynamic

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="FrmIndex" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true);
@Html.EditorForModel()

 <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}
```

Our model is:

```
    [UIHint("TextBox")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("TextBox")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DropDownList1")]
    public int deptId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DropDownList2")]
    public int orgId { get; set; }
```

Since the deptId  and orgId are foreign keys, we need to populate all possible values from their respective tables and user can choose.

The problem is having more DropDownList editor templates.

Is there any way that it can be best handled???

Suppose for some other model having 5 foreign keys, and we will have 5 DropDownList editor templates which is looking odd.

DropDownList1.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownList1, "Choose..." ,  new { @class ="combo"})
```

DropDownList2.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownList2, "Choose..." ,  new { @class ="combo"})
```

Please advise if there are any other options also that this can be best implemented.

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17760548/2911047