# EditorTemplate DropDown gets wrong id and cant get validated

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, mvc-editor-templates

I have made an EditorTemplate in MVC 4 with this code:

```
@model Drexx.Models.Account
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LevelId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LevelId, String.Empty)
```

My View has this code:

```
@Html.EditorForModel();
```

My Model has this code:

```
[UIHint("LevelDropDown")]
[DisplayName("Level")]
public int LevelId { get; set; }
public virtual Level Level { get; set; }
```

My Controller has this code in the Get:

```
ViewBag.LevelId = new SelectList(db.Level, "Id", "Name");
```

My Controller has this code in the Post:

```
ViewBag.LevelId = new SelectList(db.Level, "Id", "Name", account.LevelId);
```

This is how the source code looks when i run it:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Level must be a number." data-val-required="Feltet Level skal udfyldes." id="LevelId_LevelId" name="LevelId.LevelId">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Normal</option>
    <option value="2">Admin</option>
</select>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LevelId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

why is it making the id of the dropdown into "LevelId_LevelId" and the name into "LevelId.LevelId"?
The dropdown works and shows what it should, but the validation dont work since the id/name is wrong. the validation highlights the dropdown, but it does not display the error message.

The dropdown worked perfectly fine before i moved it into EditorTemplate/before i started using EditorForModel

Im new to EditorTemplates so have a hard time figuring out what could cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Model should look like this:

```
[DisplayName("Level")]
[UIHint("LevelId")]
[Required]
public int? LevelId { get; set; }
```

The EditorTemplate should look like this:

```
@model int?
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LevelId, String.Empty)
```

It is very important that i put the "?" after the int because i have a default value in the dropdown.

I didnt have to create a ViewModel for the dropdown.

This is how the source ended up looking after the fix:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Level must be a number." data-val-required="Feltet Level skal udfyldes." id="LevelId" name="LevelId">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Normal</option>
        <option value="2">Admin</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LevelId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks for all the suggestions Darin Dimitrov, but they didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some confusion here. You have decorated your `LevelId` integer property with the `UIHint` attribute pointing to the custom `LevelDropDown.cshtml` editor template and yet your editor template seems to be strongly typed to the `Drexx.Models.Account` model which is incorrect.

Let's have an example of how you could achieve that. As always in ASP.NET MVC you start by designing your view model which will contain the necessary properties that your view might require:

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Level")]
    public int LevelId? { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Levels { get; set; }
}
```

then you write a controller action that will populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new AccountViewModel();
    model.LevelId = 123; // some value that you want to be used to preselect some element of the dropdown
    model.Levels = new SelectList(db.Level, "Id", "Name");

    return View(model);
}
```

and then in the corresponding view:

```
@model AccountViewModel
...
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then in the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AccountViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model AccountViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LevelId, Model.Levels, string.Empty)
```

You also have the possibility to specify the name of the template:

```
@Html.EditorForModel("Foo")
```

which will be looking for the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Foo.cshtml` template.

The `UIHint` attribute could be used when you have some more complex parent view model. For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    UIHint("LevelDropDown")
    public AccountViewModel Account { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: what should my editortemplate be strongly typed to if not account ? cant see what you are doing differently except that you dont use ViewBag.

Comment: Your editor template is strongly typed to account, but you placed your UIHint attribute on an integer property. Also because I am not using ViewBag, I have 2 different properties with different names which is the correct approach. In your ViewBag case you have a `ViewBag.LevelId` which is supposed to hold some collection and on the other hand you have a `LevelId` property with exactly the same name which is an integer.

Comment: if i put the UIHint over "public AccountViewModel Account" i get this: "Attribute 'UIHint' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations." if i put the UIHint over "public virtual Level Level { get; set; }" i get "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Drexx.Models.Account'." which i also get from having it over "public int LevelId { get; set; }"

Comment: I will have 3-4 dropdowns on the account form

Comment: In this case write a view model with 2 properties: one integer property and one `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property. Then in your main view model you could have a property of this type decorated with the `UIHint` attribute.

Comment: I have tried that now and it does not render that field "public DropDownViewModel Levels { get; set; }" since it has no idea what it is. have followed this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760271/html-editorformodel-dropdown . how do you get it to show the dropdown that are of custom type and how do you get that custom type to put it values into the LevelId when you select something ?