# How to display Enum as DropDownList in .Net MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-core, html.dropdownlistfor, editorformodel

I have a class called Options where I'm keeping a bunch of enumerables for different options.  One of these is a Sizes enumerable which is used in my Ball model.  How do I get my Size field for my Ball to display as a dropdown list when creating a new Ball?  I assume I need to make an Editor Template but I don't know what that's supposed to look like.

Here's some example code:

**Options.cs**

```
public class Options
{
    public enum Sizes
    {
        Small,
        Medium,
        Large
    };

    public enum Material
    {
        Rubber,
        Plastic,
        Metal
    };
}
```

**Ball.cs**

```
public class Ball
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Options.Sizes Size { get; set; }
    public Options.Material Material { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**
    @model WebApplication.Models.Ball

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Ball">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

How do I get EditorForModel to display the enum properties as DropDownLists with the possible values of the Enum?

Comment: EditorForModel does not create dropdownlist by its own. This might help you to find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760271/html-editorformodel-dropdown and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with a bit of help from this [source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums/)

I didn't create a helper like it suggests but I used the same principles from the helper to create a EditorTemplate for my Sizes enum.  Here's what it looks like:

**Sizes.cshtml**

```
@model Options.Sizes 

@{ 
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options.Sizes)).Cast<Options.Sizes>();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
        from value in values
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = value.ToString(),
            Value = value.ToString(),
            Selected = (value.Equals(Options.Sizes.ATX_Full))
        };
}

@Html.DropDownList("Size", items)
```

Now when I call `@Html.EditorForModel()` in my Ball.cshtml, it references this editor template and creates a dropdown with all the options in the enum.